# How to use ManyToManyField in Django Model

Tags: django

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = model.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = TextField()
    tags = ManyToManyField(‘Tag’,blank=True)
    …

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.ChatField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    …
```

I try to find a simple way to find blogs has same tags.
For example, a certain blog has tag “wood”, “desk”, “furniture”. I want to find some blogs which has at least one of the tags.

Comment: Please be specific to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation here on how to filter relationships: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

To see how to have multiple filters (a blog with a tag 'wood' Or 'desk' Or 'furniture'), see the example here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships

The code below should accomplish what you want:

```
blogs = Blog.objects.filter(tags__tag='wood').filter(tags__tag='desk').filter(tags_tag='furniture')
```

Comment: How is it possible in runtime?  In runtime, I don't know how many tags are there.

Comment: @eachone what do you mean by "in runtime"? The code I posted above allows you to find blogs which have at least one of the tags (and keeps them in a variable called 'blogs'). The amount of items inside 'blogs' is the amount of tags there are which match the filter.